# call getJson method

Tags: jquery, html, json

I want to show the data of my json file in div tag of my html page.

Here my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#driver").click(function (event) {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function (em) {
            $('#stage').html('<p>Name: ' + em.name + '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p>Age : ' + em.age + '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p> Sex: ' + em.sex + '</p>');
        });
    });
});
```

I have taken one button its id is "driver". Whenever click on button its call the data.json file and take name, age and sex nd put in div tag which is id =
"Show"

Here my data.json file code

```
{
    "em": {
        "name": "Amit",
        "age": 24,
        "sex": "Male"
    }
}
```

The Error I got:

Name: `undefined`

Age: `undefined`

Sex: `undefined`

Comment: try JSON.parse(em) first..

Comment: You're trying to access `.name` on the `object` returned, which doesn't exist, so you need to go down another level. `em.em.name`, but you should probably rename the object returned, from `em` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/rELRW/1/)**:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#driver").click(function (event) {
            $.getJSON('data.json', function (json) {
                $('#stage').html('<p>Name: ' + json.em.name + '</p>');
                $('#stage').append('<p>Age : ' + json.em.age + '</p>');
                $('#stage').append('<p> Sex: ' + json.em.sex + '</p>');
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hey manoj, thanks a lot bro.. now its working fine.. could you tell me why u say to use json in function parameter instead of my object em???

Comment: @Ammi Because `json` (can be called anything you want) refers to the whole object and not the `object` in the actual `.json` file. Once you have the whole `json object` then you can call `json.em.whatever-node`.

Comment: You can use any name instead json,refer previous comment.

Comment: You could have just changed it to 'em.em.name' without changing the name and it would have worked, but I think Manoj's code was for clarity to let you know you are passing through the whole json object.

Comment: yeah u said right @Manoj i used another name instead of jason.. its working properly...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var obj = {
    "em": {
        "name": "Amit",
        "age": 24,
        "sex": "Male"
    }
};
console.log(obj.em.name);
console.log(obj.em.age);
console.log(obj.em.sex);
```

In your case

```
     $.getJSON('data.json', function (obj) {
        $('#stage').html('<p>Name: ' + obj.em.name + '</p>');
        $('#stage').append('<p>Age : ' + obj.em.age + '</p>');
        $('#stage').append('<p> Sex: ' + obj.em.sex + '</p>');
    });
```